# Input.GetAxisRaw not returning a 0 in Unity

Tags: unity, input

this is extremely frustrating, basically Input.GetAxisRaw only ever returns a 1 or -1. see my code below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider;

    private Vector3 moveDelta;

    private void Start()
    {
        boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        // Reset moveDelta
        moveDelta = new Vector3(x,y,0);

        // Swap sprite direction, whether you're going right or left 
        if(moveDelta.x > 0){
            transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        }
        else if(moveDelta.x < 0){
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1,1,1);
        }

        //Make this thing move!
        transform.Translate(moveDelta * Time.deltaTime);

        Debug.Log(x);
        Debug.Log(y);

    }
}
```

Here are screenshots from the input settings, I haven't changed anything:

[image: Horizontal Input Setting]

[image: Vertical Input Setting]

Please help, I am new to Unity. Could not find anything that work, the other related post was unanswered.

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem? I'm having the same one, character starts moving with out any buttons being pressed but when i stop and press play again it works fine. The code have been working fine for a few months and a week back its been acting strange. I tested an older project with the same results. What Unity version are you using? I'm on 2021.2.7f1 Took a break from writing to try something and noticed that both projects with version 2021.2.7f1 has the problem and my other one on version 2020.3.18f1 is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully I can post with zero reputation! I had an issue similar to this one. GetAxisRaw was pegged at 1 on vertical with no input from keyboard and no controllers connected.

I did have a 3Dconnexion spacemouse installed at one point and the utilities for that were installed and running. The spacemouse was not connected.

After shutting down all 3dconnexion utilities and rebooting Unity the issue went away.

All this is to say that if you encounter this issue it is very possible that it is related to software that is installed on your system. it's useful to check on a different system.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Ok this is definitely helpful, I had a 3dconnexion mouse too and disabling the drivers fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are polling the keyboard, `InputGetAxisRaw` will *always* only return -1, 0 or 1 per the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html). Use [`InputGetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) instead, assuming you don't want to do your own smoothing.

I've tested your code, zero *does* get returned when no keys are pressed:

[image: console]

Try polling/ logging `Input.GetAxis()` instead of `Input.GetAxisRaw` to see what kinds of values your keyboard is returning when idle. My guess is that it is returning some very small, but non-zero, value. If I'm right, you'll want to change your logic to move the sprite when the axis value is not simply greater than zero, but greater than that small threshold.

Comment: Hi, so as long as I use `Input.GetAxis()` or `Input.GetAxisRaw()` it only ever returns a -1, or 1, even on GetAxis() it never returns a 0. I suspect it is hardware related but i disabled any unneeded input devices and it still doesn't work. A really interesting case happens though when I stop the game and then restart it, all of a sudden it does work. But if I make any changes and restart again, I get the error again.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, seems also that pressing ESC to exit mouse focus on play window and focus editor window fixes.